# PyQGIS data provider connecting to wrong table

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geopackage

I have an issue with PyQGIS somehow connecting to the incorrect table and using the wrong tables.

I have a geopackage, which I'm connecting to via filepath. When I report on the number of features, or the attribute list, the number of features or attribute list is different to the actual values.

eg: design_extent table, as per Properties in QGIS window.

[image: screen grab from QGIS GUI]

However when using the following code, it returns 6 records.

```
path_to_design_db = "\\\\iomsfi01\\rtiomp\\SKM_WR\\WR_DES\\Technical\\GIS\\gpkg\\design.gpkg"
project_area = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_design_db, "design_extent", "ogr")
project_area.featureCount()

6
```

Additionally, the field listing is as follows:

[image: Field Listing]

But when I run the following code

```
for i in a_feat.fields():
    print(i)
```

The listing of fields is as follows:

```
<QgsField: fid (Integer64)>
<QgsField: date_loaded (Date)>
<QgsField: reference_drawing (String)>
<QgsField: project (String)>
<QgsField: design_number (String)>
```

It's as if the connection to the datasource is pointing to the wrong table.
But I was able to replicate the same issue, with a completely different table in a completely different Geopackage.

Running QGIS 3.22

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying a table within the GeoPackage, therefore the feature count is likely for the first table that is found by `QgsVectorLayer`.

Try this:

```py
# specify the table to load
name = 'design_extent'

# create the vector layer by specifying the `layername` (based on the name in your screenshot)
project_area = QgsVectorLayer(f"{path_to_design_db}|layername={name}", "design_extent", "ogr")

# get the feature count
print(project_area.featureCount())
```

Comment: yep thats it, just realised this is specifically mentioned in the documentation cookbook as well. do'h! Thanks.